# Drupal: New theme breaks site with error message

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, themes, drupal-theming

I recently bought a drupal theme package from Themeforest. Looked great and I can't wait to get going with it but I am running into a problem. Quite a big one. After I set up my Drupal page with Acquia Dev Desktop and installed it I try adding my new theme. I am probably doing something wrong because what happens is this: it shows up in my themes on the site but the moment I set it as active, the site reload to refresh, the site breaks, and the only thing I see is a fatal error page indicating that a certain function cannot be executed. Now, I'd love to show the error but I have (for the 7th time now) set up the page again to give it another try. I am going to add two images below: one of the theme package, and one of the drupal folder on my local drive. Somebody that can help me out telling me what needs to go where (e.g. what do I need to do with the database.sql files)?

Really looking forward to your help!

Take care

Folders (left theme package):

[image]

Comment: What is the error you are getting.

Comment: There must be some installation documentation. Check on that "Documentation" folder for installing instructions.